# Java/Scala resource consumption and load

Tags: java, scala, load, scalability, protocol-buffers

I am developing a web application in Scala. Its a simple application which will take data on a port from clients (JSON or ProtoBufs) and do some computation using a database server and then reply the client with a JSON / Protobuf object.

Its not a very heavy application. 1000 lines of code max. It will create a thread on every client request. The time it takes right now between getting the request and replying back is between 20 - 40ms.

I need an advice on what kind of hardware / setup should i use to serve 3000+ such requests per second. I need to procure hardware to put at my data center.

Anybody who has some experience deploying java apps at scale, please advice. Should i use one big box with 2 - 4 Xeon 5500s with 32 GB RAMs or multiple smaller machines.

UPDATE - we dont have many clients. 3 - 4 of them. Requests will be from these 3 of them.

Comment: First optimize your app by not creating a thread on every client request. Use a thread pool. Then measure and experiment.

Comment: You can try using SoapUI or similar tools to measure the load. This way you can test how a certain type of machine handles the load your application requires.

Comment: forgot to mention an update. Now i am trying to use HTTP pipelines in a thread to get multiple requests from a single socket. So number of threads should go down.

Comment: are 3000 req/sec a steady state? Also what's the latency you need to provide? Also you mention you have a Redis server - can it currently handle 3000+ req/sec ?

Comment: Yea redis does comfortably if you have the entire database fit in memory. 3000 per sec is peak hours. Will be down at night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each request takes on average 30 ms, a single core can handle only 30 requests per second. Supposing that your app scales linearly (the best scenario you can expect), then you will need at least 100 cores to reach 3000 req/s. Which is more than 2-4 Xeon.

Worst, if you app relies on IO or on DB (like most useful applications), you will get a sublinear scaling and you may need a lot more...

So the first thing to do is to analyze and optimize the application. Here are a few tips:

- Creating a thread is **expensive**, try to create a limited number of threads and reuse them among requests (in java see [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for example).
- If you app is IO-intensive: try to reduce IO calls as much a possible, using a cache in memory and give a try to non-blocking IO.
- If you app is dependent of a database, consider caching and try a distributed solution if possible.

Comment: Yes its dependent upon a database but that should not be a bottleneck because its a 10 GB redis-based key-value store on a nearby machine with 16 GB RAM. So the entire DB is in its memory and reads are fast.

Comment: You should measure it to be sure it's not a bottleneck... (if reducing the number of threads, is not enough for you)

Comment: do you think using cloud is good for such an app ??? or should we use our own cluster. ??

Comment: It's not possible to tell before you optimize your code and you check the scalability. Then you can evaluate your requirements and you compare cloud offers with cluster prices (don't forget to price the cluster admin and maintenance).